# manage Asynchronous sequence in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In my project I want remove some rows first then afterwards insert new rows.

But some times what happens is it inserts the new rows first then afterwards removes the starting rows.

To solve this problem I need to manage the operations in a proper sequence.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern/problem with Silverlight as pretty much "everything" is asynchronous (for good reasons).

Depending on how your Adds and Removes are triggered, you could queue up tasks (e.g. a list of delegates) and have each task execute the next one off the list when they complete.

The alternative is going to sound a little complex, but the solution we came up with is to create a SequentialAsynchronousTaskManager class that operates in a similar way to the SilverlightTest class which uses EnqueueConditional() methods to add wait conditions and EnqueueCallback()s to execute code.

It basically holds a list of delegates (which can be simple Lambda expressions) and either executes it regularly until it returns true (EnqueueConditional) or just executes some code (EnqueueCallback).